# Advantages of passing DOM element over jQuery object via data()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Other than personal preference and assuming both work (which they do in my examples below), are there any reasons why one would wish to pass a DOM element via `data()` over a jQuery object?

For instance, is there any benefits of using one of the two options below over the other?

Option 1

```
$(".action").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").data('elem', this).dialog("open");
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    var elem = $(this).data('elem');
    var stuff = $(elem).parent().data('stuff');
  }
});
```

Option 2

```
$(".action").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").data('elem', $(this).parent()).dialog("open");
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    var elem = $(this).data('elem');
    var stuff = elem.data('stuff');
  }
});
```

Comment: `data` just stores entries in a named-entry lookup table per element, so you can store anything in it. One thing to bear in mind is references being left behind so perhaps the simpler raw DOM elements would be better?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie  I know it isn't a big deal, but all things being equal, wondered if one used more memory/etc than the other.

Comment: A jQuery object is an extra object on top of the DOM element, but if that object exists at any time, the overhead is just a retained jQuery object in data. Small but it is extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, storing the jQuery object will put slightly more memory into a state where it cannot be garbage-collected, but the overhead this represents is really minimal. I'd focus more on ensuring that the code is maintainable.

From a maintainability perspective, I think the biggest issue here is that you've got two pieces of code that need to stay in sync with one another. If you change the name of the key ("elem") in one, it'll need to change in the other. If you change what you pass from one, you'll also need to change the expectations in the other. Do everything you can to keep these expectations synchronized. It may be worthwhile to have more code (and slightly more overhead) just to decrease the chances of these expectations getting out of sync.

I recognize that this is a simplistic example, but looking at the code you've posted, it seems to me like maybe the best way to achieve both goals (performance and maintainability) is to reduce the scope of the information you pass in even further:

```
$(".action").click(function() {
  $("#dialog").data('stuff', $(this).parent().data('stuff')).dialog("open");
});

$("#dialog").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  open: function() {
    var stuff = $(this).data('stuff');
  }
});
```

By moving knowledge of `.action`'s DOM structure out of `#dialog`-related code and into `.action`-related code, you're far more likely to be able to keep your code correct if you end up changing `.action` and its relation to the elements near it. (In fact, you might consider changing `.parent()` to `.parents('.whatever')` so that you don't have to change anything if your HTML structure changes slightly.) This also has the convenient side-effect of only storing the "stuff" you actually need in memory while this dialog exists.

Comment: Is one version easier to maintain than the other?  Seems like they have the same requirements.  Or, off topic, is there a better way to pass info to the dialog?  I searched that question before posting this one, and all I saw was using `data()` similar to what I did.

Comment: @user1032531: See my updated answer for one suggestion. The "best" way is going to be both open to opinion and specific to the way you're using this.

Comment: Thanks StriplingWarrior.  By the way, I am using it on a list which each item has an data-attribute indicating the items primary key, and when the dialog is opened, ajax is used to get the record using that primary key.